# text present or not (Selenium, Python)

Tags: python, selenium

How I can know, that there is a text or not. I used this code:

```
pricelist = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@id='scroll']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div")
if EC.text_to_be_present_in_element(By.XPATH(".//*[@id='scroll']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]")):
    price = pricelist[1].text
elif EC.text_to_be_present_in_element(By.XPATH(".//*[@id='scroll']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]")):
    price = pricelist[2].text
else:
    price = pricelist[3].text
```

Problem:

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Your use of the Expected Condition is not correct. This EC compares the text in the element returned by the locator matches the text you supply as the second argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Xpath to check length of text in the element. See code below.

```
price = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='scroll']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[string-length(text()) > 1]").text
```

You can change the text length in xpath like `/div[string-length(text()) > 10]` to find an element which contains more than 10 characters.

Comment: You should change to element instead of the plural elements. Currently it will call the function text on the list instead of webelement

Answer (score 1):

`By.XPATH` is not a method, but simple string. Correct usage is

```
EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, xpath_expression)))
```

If you want to match element that contains text, use `[text()]` predicate:

```
".//*[@id='scroll']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[text()]"
```

Comment: Thank you! What if there are strings in both element. One string can store more than 10 symbols. But place is unknown

Answer (score 0):

I have used another method:

```
pricelist = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@id='scroll']/div[%d]/div/div[2]/div" %num)
for prc in pricelist:
    if len(prc.text) < 10 and len(prc.text) > 0:
        price = prc.text
```

This method is slow enough, but the most readeable